# Who is the third head of the dragon?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the series [*A Song of Ice and Fire*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire), dragons always occur in groups of three - The three conquering dragons, the three eggs etc.

Somewhere, it's also implied that there should be three dragon-controllers (I forgot where, but this is what I remember).

> So if Danaerys is one, Jon the second.

Who is the third head? Has there been any discussions about this somewhere?

Comment: Arrgh, never mouse over spoilers for a 4 (of 6) book series, when you are only at the beginning of book 3 X|

Comment: @johnc:I believe that what you took to be a spoiler (about John) is actually only fan speculation, albeit one that is agreed  upon a really high number of people.

Comment: Cheers, it's not a bad plot twist either way, though how it comes to eventuate, I have no idea yet. Good to see the plot lines coming together (though it was inevitable)

Comment: @johnc: "of 6"? There are only 5 books published, last I checked.

Comment: @b_jonas Give it a few years. I'll eventually be right.

Comment: Its planned to be 7 books.  Book 6 is title The Winds of Winter.  Book 7 is planned to be A Memory of Spring IIRC.

Comment: "dragons always occur in groups of three" is not at all correct. Aegon and his sister's had three, and Dany has three. There's a few hundred years of dragons in between that have never been stated to come in a set of three.

Comment: Also, how's this question not Future Works nor Primarily Opinion Based?

Comment: @Paul It is under today's standards but when asked I don't think the FWP existed and close rules were more lax anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common suggestion for the third head is

> Tyrion.

Comment: Can you give a link to some such discussion?

Comment: http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/37886-tyrion-a-targaryen/

Comment: Supporting quote from GRRM: "Three heads of the dragon... yes... but the third will not nessesarily BE a Targaryen..." - [GRRM - SSM](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Category/C92/P210)

Answer (score 6):

Now that *A Dance with Dragons* has been released I believe it's worth adding another answer to this question.

***A Dance with Dragons*** spoiler

---

> It seems more likely now that one of the dragons is Aegon Targaryen. Aegon Targaryen was the second child and only son of Prince Rhaegar Targaryen and Elia Martell. It is revealed that the baby murdered during the Sack of King's Landing was that of a peasant who Lord Varys put in the cot. Varys then hid baby Aegon. When Robert Baratheon and the realm falsely believed him dead, Varys had agents smuggle him across the narrow sea. [Aegon_Targaryen @ asoif wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen).

Also

> It now seems possible, although not certain, that Jon Snow isn't one of the three; so the other answers could still be just as accurate.

Comment: My thoughts after DWD are that your first theory is correct but I'm not sold on the second as I'm pretty sure he's coming back.

Comment: I felt the possibility should be mentioned for completeness, but I believe you're correct. And I certainly hope you are!

Comment: I'm not convinced hes actually Aegon though.  Mummers Dragon and all.

Comment: [Is Aegon really Aegon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115364/why-does-the-golden-company-raise-the-banners-for-a-targaryen/131317#131317)

Comment: @Aegon You tell us. _Are_ you really Aegon?

Answer (score 1):

While Mike's answer is correct , I want to say that most of the discussions seem to be weak.

> I believe it much more likely that Daenerys' brother was the third head. After all, nowhere does it say that one of the heads can't die after he/she is born.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. He just seemed spoiled, not like his sister at all. She obviously is different, touching flames, etc. It's hard to have this discussion without spoilers...

Comment: @Travis:I rephrased my answer to make it clear what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

> In Book 4, Maester Aemon, dying, says to Sam that he thought he'd be the third.

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler:

It has been discussed. The most popular contenders for the third head are:

> 1. Tyrion (he has a fascination with dragons, also there is a theory that Tyrion may unknowingly be the son of Aerys and Joanna)
>   2. Bran (he's a powerful warg and maybe dragons can be warged, also he has a connection with 'flying')
>   3. Aegon (though there is some speculation that he may not actually be Aegon Targaryen)