# How many Targaryen cadet dynasties still remain in Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Okay, so, I know of several Targaryen cadet dynasties (Blackfyre, Bloodraven, Bittersteel), but are there any other High Valyrian cadet families in Westeros that survived the purging of the Targaryens, no matter how minuscule and powerless the family?

Velaryons and other families that do not directly stem from the Targaryens are disqualified, regardless of how much Targaryen blood they have.

Comment: Tyrion believes that [Brown Ben Plumm](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ben_Plumm) has `"two drops [of dragon blood]"` in him.

Comment: Also, don't discount the Velaryons so readily; they still consider themselves as "cousins" of Targaryens.

Comment: Relevant: [Case of House Blackfyre - Spoilers Alert](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115364/why-does-the-golden-company-raise-the-banners-for-a-targaryen/131317#131317)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there are none. The Targaryen family tree is quite sparse due to several civil wars that have decimated their numbers. Add to that their preference to intermarry rather than mix it up with the other families. As of now, the only known Targaryen descendant is Daenerys. Descendants of the Great Bastards (Bittersteel and Blackfyre) almost certainly still exist in the Free Cities, most probably as part of the Golden Company mercenary group.

A Dance with Dragons spoiler ahead:

> There's also the self proclaimed Aegon VI, though we are not sure how valid his claim is.

Answer (score 7):

Spoilers for all books and TV seasons up to the end of *A Dance With Dragons*/Season 5.

Known Targaryens who are still alive:

> **Daenerys Targaryen**,
>  **Brynden Rivers/Bloodraven**,
>  **Stannis Baratheon** (in the books),
>  **Shireen Baratheon** (in the books)

Known Targaryens who have died during the series:

> **Viserys Targaryen**,
>  **Maester Aemon**,
>  **Robert Baratheon**,
>  **Renly Baratheon**,
>  **Stannis Baratheon** (in the TV series),
>  **Shireen Baratheon** (in the TV series)

Possible/Suspected Targaryens:

> **Aegon VI** (claims to be Rhaegar's son, more likely Illyrio's son),
>  **Tyrion Lannister** (Aerys was fond of his mother),
>  **Cersei & Jaime Lannister** (ditto),
>  **Jon Snow** (R + L = J),
>  any **Blackfyres** in the female line of descent who are still kicking around in Essos,
>  any descendants of Aerion **Brightflame** who are still kicking around in Essos,
>  **Illyrio** (maybe a Blackfyre),
>  **Varys** (maybe a Brightflame),
>  **Joffrey, Tommen & Myrcella Baratheon** (believed to be Robert Baratheon's children and thus have Targaryen ancestry, but we know they're not)

My Personal Crackpot Theory:

> **Littlefinger**'s grandmother (who we know came from Essos) was a Blackfyre, and he has Targaryen blood and will end up as King. He is already quite like Henry Tudor, who ended up as Henry VII after winning the Wars of the Roses, and Henry Tudor's claim to the throne was because he was descended from the Plantagenets in an illegitimate female line.

Comment: Littlefinger is a Blackfyre? Can you back that up with a citation?

Comment: @TLP No citation, that's why it's a crackpot theory. It's just a possible answer to the question "If Littlefinger was going to end up like Henry VII, how could he have Targaryen ancestry in an illegitimate female line".

Comment: Aren't the current Martells a descendant of the first Daenerys, Daughter of Aegon IV?