# Did Lyanna Stark know about the sack of King's Landing and the death of Rhaegar's children?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After reading this question: [Why are there two characters named Aegon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/why-are-there-two-characters-named-aegon) , it occurred to me that **Lyanna Stark could have already known about her step children's deaths** at the hand of the Mountain during the sack of King's Landing by Tywin Lannister and company.

**Using evidence from the books or the show, is it possible to establish a timeline of events that could allow for that possibility?** <sup>1</sup>

<sub>1. Assuming that she did know about the death of the first-born son of Rhaegar Targaryan (also named Aegon Targaryan), it would adequately explain why she named her son Aegon as well in my mind...</sub>

---

**Edit for clarity:**

I am aware of the FAegon story-line from the books, and it looks like that story-line has probably been dropped from the show (although who knows? Maybe Cercei's Golden Company will end up being led by FAegon in season 8... What a twist!). Even so, if there are book passages which lend credence to the theory that Lyanna Stark knew of the death of Rhaegar's children, that's more than good enough for me.

Comment: Hmm, good question, also there are clues in the discussions between Ned and co and the kingsguards - if I remember right they seemed pretty well informed about how everything had gone down

Comment: The books make it pretty... *complicated*. As far as we know, Rhaegar's first-born Aegon would allegedly be alive and well (though completely under the radar), and his storyline is mangled with other characters in the show, which leads to believe showrunners dropped that arc.

Comment: “Maybe Cercei's Golden Company will end up being led by FAegon in season 8... What a twist!” — Yeah, the show definitely needs *another* Aegon Targaryan at this point.

Comment: With just six episodes left, they will be rushed to wrap it all up.  I anticipate few people will be happy with the end and that the interviews with the actors are preparing people for this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We certainly know that since the fall of King's Landing, the siege of Storm's End was lifted by Ned Stark (evidence in following quote soon). Ned went to Storm's End after arguing with Robert Baratheon over the killing of Rhaegar's children. We can assume that news of the fall of King's Landing was flowing across the realm in the meantime (ravens, refugees, people, etc.). Certainly the new King would be informing Lords at castles, either to celebrate victory, or demand the bending of the knee.

The Tower of Joy is near Nightsong and Kingsgrave. Kingsgrave is the seat of House Manwoody. Nightsong is the seat of House Caron. Castles such as this would be the source of supplies, and news. As long as we assume the airspeed velocity of a laden raven is greater than that an army (or a band of 7 people on horseback), it is certainly possible for news to have reached the Tower of Joy with the events of King's Landing.

> “I looked for you on the Trident,” Ned said to them.
>
> “We were not there,” Ser Gerold answered.
>
> “Woe to the Usurper if we had been,” added Ser Oswell.
>
> “When King’s Landing fell, Ser Jaime slew your king with a golden sword, and I wondered where you were.”
>
> “Far away,” Ser Gerold said, “or Aerys would yet sit the Iron Throne, and our false brother would burn in seven hells.”
>
> “I came down on Storm’s End to lift the siege,” Ned told them, “and the Lords Tyrell and Redwyne dipped their banners, and all their knights bent the knee to pledge us fealty. I was certain you would be among them.”
>
> ”Our knees do not bend easily,” said Ser Arthur Dayne.
>
> “Ser Willem Darry is fled to Dragonstone with your queen and Prince Viserys. I thought you might have sailed with him.”
>
> “Ser Willem is a good man, and true,” said Ser Oswell.
>
> “But not of the Kingsguard,” Ser Gerold pointed out. “The Kingsguard does not flee.”
>
> “Then, or now,” said Ser Arthur. He donned his helm.
>
> ”We swore a vow,” explained old Ser Gerold.
>
> Ned’s wraiths moved up beside him, shadow swords in their hands. They were seven against three. “And now it begins,” said Ser Arthur Dayne, the Sword of the Morning. He unsheathed Dawn and held it with both hands. The blade was pale as milkglass, alive with light.
>
> “No,” said Ned with sadness in his voice. “Now it ends.”

The Kingsguard are clearly aware of the fall of King's Landing. Although to be fair, they only respond of that knowledge after Ned Stark's first comment regarding King's Landing's fall, and Jaime Lannister's betrayal. They don't betray any knowledge aside from that already mentioned by Ned Stark. So as far as actual proof whether Lyanna Stark knew of the specific events of Aegon's fate, is unclear.

That said, there is also no book evidence that Lyanna Stark named her son Aegon, or would have in any way done something with the knowledge of the death of Aegon Targaryen in King's Landing. It is entirely possible that a show writer figured Aegon was a cool name, and a cool reference to the removed storyline of Aegon Targaryen in the books, without thinking of the implications.

Comment: +1 Still gonna keep this open to see if anyone else has any more compelling evidence but will probably accept this in a few days if not.

Comment: Also, a timeline would be pretty cool if you have one...

Comment: You're not even going to source the Monty Python (un)laden raven joke from this stack?! Appalled ;-P

Comment: Another issue is that even if they received all information about what happened and knew of the children's deaths we don't know if they would have informed Lyanna. She could've been kept in the dark for any number of reasons and no way for her to find out.