# If Jon Snow became King of the Seven Kingdoms what would his regnal number be?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We see Sam revealing Jon's true identity to him at the crypts of Winterfell. There he refers to him as

> Aegon the Sixth. 
>
>  However, Aegon VI was the son of Rhaegar and Elia Martell and was born before Jon Snow. So Jon Snow should be Aegon VII Targaryen.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [Why are there two characters named Aegon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168222/why-are-there-two-characters-named-aegon)

Comment: Erm, whatever he wants it to be?

Comment: Number is not personal property, but property of relationship between person and the realm, i.e. he would get number iff he was crowned, not just by the fact he existed. You may check RL example [James VI and I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_VI_and_I), for Scotland he was sixth, for England and Ireland he was first of his name.

Comment: It should be obvious that huge spoilers do not go into the title of a question. Have a little think before you hit "submit".

Comment: @Randal'Thor The one the OP wrote before TheLethalCarrot kindly fixed it.

Comment: I may add that in real history on Earth regnal numbers began to be officially used by lowly and insignificant kings in western European culture about 1500 to 1700.  It was very, very rare for mere kings to use regnal numbers during the middle ages, when it was normal only for Holy Roman Emperors and popes. I don't know  if "Byzantine" emperors used regnal numbers or who was the first ruler to officially use a regnal number - possibly emperor Otto III "The Wonder of the World" about 1000.  In England Edward IV may have been the first, in the title of his son Richard duke of York.

Answer (score 27):

The name became vacant after Clegane decided to paint the wall of the Red Keep with whatever he had with him.

Joke aside, Aegon would be named [Aegon VI](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar)) only if he would have been crowned.

[Aegon, son of King Aerys II Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Aerys_II)) and Queen Rhaella, didn't have any number, such as lot of other [Aegons](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen), like [Aegon, son of Aenys I](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Aenys_I)), who became the Uncrowned after his uncle usurped the Throne.

As Aegon, son of Rhaegar and Elia, supposedly died during the sack of Kings Landing, the last Aegon that ruled is still Aegon V.

> Therefore, would Jon Snow claim the crown as a Targaryen, he would be the sixth Aegon to rule.

Comment: _"Aegon, son of King Aerys II Targaryen and Queen Rhaella, didn't have any number, such as lot of other Aegons, like Aegon, son of Aenys I, who became the Uncrowned after his uncle usurped the Throne."_ Nice title. Can imagine Ser Davos reading this out in court.

Comment: Just go the Doctor Who method and call him Aegon [Six And A Half Or Something](https://youtu.be/8C7Ys_hhHCA?t=12).

Comment: Aegon Targaryen, sixth of his name, the King in the North, the Watcher on the Wall, the Snowy Bastard, the Night's Watch Brother from Another Mother (of Dragons), Thorne's Pin-cushion, Giver to the Wildling of his Dingaling.

Comment: Weren't it the walls of Dragonstone, not the Red Keep?

Comment: @Paul He nearly has as many names as Tormund... And half as many as Dany.

Answer (score 8):

King George VI wasn't the (sixth person named George) who was king, he was the sixth (person named George who was king). That is, he was the sixth King George, not the sixth George. It's not like there were only five people named George in the history of England, or even in the history of the Windsors, before him. (And please, no nitpicking about whether his name was Albert or George, or whether he was a Windsor or Saxe-Coburg and Gotha, etc.)

Comment: (King George) the Sixth, not King (George the Sixth). I guess we can establish the order of precedence here :P